# Iterable React Native SDK - InAppConsume is called incorrectly

Tags: react-native, sdk, iterable

we are currently implementing Iterable React Native SDK. We have discovered that when the app is launched, for some reasons, the inAppConsume() will call automatically which in turns consume all our in-app notification of the user. We cannot override this potential default behaviour. We believe this is a bug. Does anyone here know how to resolve this?

We tried to suppress the call without any success.